# SMJobBless causes kSMErrorDomainFramework error 5 - The tool at the specified path is not valid

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

## Running SMJobBless:

(PrefPane project xcode version 4 Build 4A304a)

```
SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, @"com.coderama.coderamaHelper", authRef, &err);
```

## Causes this error:

```
System Preferences[22312:903] Bless Error: Error Domain=kSMErrorDomainFramework Code=5 UserInfo=0x2005790e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kSMErrorDomainFramework error 5 - The tool at the specified path is not valid.)"
```

Below are my plists.

Can anyone decipher the error message so I can attempt to troubleshoot this? I have gone over all of my plists to make sure the names match-up.

### coderama-info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.coderama.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2012 coderama. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>coderama</string>
    <key>NSPrefPaneIconFile</key>
    <string>show_wireframe_zoom_24.gif</string>
    <key>NSPrefPaneIconLabel</key>
    <string>coderama</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>coderama</string>
    <key>SMPrivilegedExecutables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.coderama.coderamaHelper</key>
        <string>identifier com.coderama.coderamaHelper and certificate leaf[subject.CN] = &quot;Joe Developer&quot;</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### coderamaHelper-info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.coderama.coderamaHelper</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>coderamaHelper</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>SMAuthorizedClients</key>
    <array>
        <string>identifier com.coderama.coderama and certificate leaf[subject.CN] = &quot;Joe Developer&quot;</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### coderamaHelper-Launchd.plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.coderama.coderamaHelper</string>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.coderama.coderamaHelper.mach</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Apple developer replied to me stating that `SMJobBless` only works with Applications only.

Comment: Specifically: [on launchd-dev](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2012-March/001004.html).

Answer (score 9):

I went to this error too, at first check again the steps declared in the readme.txt of the SMJobless project:

1. In the application go to: Target/Build Phases /Copy Files and make
   sure that the parameters are correctly assigned: Destination = wrapper,
   subpath = Contents/Library/LaunchServices, and finally load the
   daemon or service into the project.
2. In the application go to the file info.plist and check for the following key :"Tools owned after installation" and set it up to=
   identifier com.acme.MyService and certificate leaf[subject.CN] =
   "MyCertificate" . You must replace MyService and MyCertificate by
   your own ones.
3. In the helper tool  or daemon go to  info.plist file. Here you have to add some key/value pairs, the first one is: "Clients allowed
   to add and remove tool"  which must be set to "identifier
   com.acme.MyApp and certificate leaf[subject.CN] = "MyCertificate"
   ,remember replace MyApp and MyCertificate by your own ones.
4. Finally make sure that THE DAEMON is embedded in the executable itself before Build it, this is accomplished by this way:
   In the    helper tool or daemon go to target/Build
   Settings/Linking/Other Linker Flags and add the following:

   -sectcreate
   __TEXT
   __info_plist
   MyDaemon/info.plist
   -sectcreate
   __TEXT
   _launchd_plist
   MyDaemon/myDaemon-launchd.plist

Make sure to replace MyDaemon for the correct values of your own development. Be careful with the names of your info and launchd files.

**IMPORTANT TIP**: THE NAME OF THE DAEMON OR SERVICE  MUST CORRESPOND TO THE SAME NAME WRITTEN  IN  THE INFO.PLIST AND LAUNCHD.PLIST FILES OTHERWISE IT WILL GENERATE THE ERROR `kSMErrorDomainFramework` error 5 - The tool at the specified path is not valid.

Comment: I have the different error: kSMErrorDomainFramework error 3 - The client and tool did not match requirements.   I have check everything from the list above. But the error is still here.

Comment: The requirements for heper and main app are the same.  So, this is strange why I get error.

Comment: This was a tricky one... choose all the plist values carefully and make sure you add the "com.acme.myApp and certificate leaf[subject.CN] = "Mac Developer: Rudy Aramayo (R2287HQBC8)" exactly...Copy the samplecode for this and read the readme carefully... it states all the directions to get this to work...http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html... but only applies to applications and not pref panes

Comment: @Sauron: I had error 3 too and in my situation it was an accented letter in my self-signed certificate name what was causing the problem. I created another one without the accented letter, changed that in Xcode and the .plist files, and finally `SMJobBless` returned `YES`.

Comment: @willyMon: Can you explain how I get the information that is suppose to replace "MyCertificate"

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when the helper tool is not bundled in the correct location, and so `SMJobBless()` can't find the tool for installation. In the `Build Phases` section of your main application target, you have to add a `Copy Files` build phase. Add your helper tool, set the destination to `Wrapper` and the subpath to `Contents/Library/LaunchServices`, and `SMJobBless()` will be able to find your helper tool.

Comment: I didn't have this setup so I went back to @xdissent's Elevator example as well as the SMJobBless projects and mimicked the settings of the `Targets` but I am still getting the same error... Any other ideas? Does this have anything to do with my project being a PrefPane?

Comment: I wouldn't be amazed if SMJobBless did the wrong thing for pref panes, so yes, that could be the problem. Sorry, I missed that in your original question.

Comment: Now that I think about it, `Contents/Library/LaunchServices` makes a lot of sense for applications, but now that I think about it, it doesn't necessarily make sense for preference panes. Perhaps the helper tool needs to be located elsewhere... Unfortunately, `SMJobBless()` and its documentation is infuriatingly unhelpful in diagnosing any problems, so I honestly don't know if there's a way to check if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me anyway. I really appreciate it. I actually got more achieved by looking at your S/O post regarding this issue with the help of @xdissent than with any of the documentation supplied by apple

Comment: Thanks. I really hope Apple improves the documentation for this kind of stuff, or at least provides more in-depth documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the documentation for SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/ServiceManagementFwRef/ServiceManagement_h/#//apple_ref/c/func/SMJobBless) for the list of requirements.  My guess is that you missed step 1 (code-signing both the tool and your app) or step 5 (copying the tool to the correct place in your app wrapper).

Also, `[NSString @"com.coderama.coderamaHelper"]` makes no sense. Just write `@"com.coderama.coderamaHelper"`.

If all else fails, look at what [the sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) does and follow its example.

Comment: I thought setting up the plist keys was signing them but after looking up the `CodeSigningGuide` it seems i have to actually run `codesign`. Could this be causing the error above? If so, why wouldn't the error say that the tool isn't signed as opposed to saying it's not valid?

Comment: You don't have to run codesign yourself. In Xcode, in your target build settings, set Code Signing Identity to something other than "Don't Code Sign", and then Xcode will do it for you. See the ReadMe.txt in the sample code for more detailed instructions.  I wouldn't count on the error message being particularly helpful.

Comment: I've already done those steps, thanks for letting me know that I didn't hav to go down the track of the `codesign` util

Comment: Is it possible to use SMJobBless from inside a framework project?